# IE6: Images are stretched for a split second with height:auto

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-6

I have height:auto set, but I'm noticing that small thumbnail images are being stretched vertically in Internet Explorer 6 for a split second, then conforming to their correct height.

One thing to note, in the HTML, the image tag looks like this:

```
<img src="http://location" width="96" />
```

Will setting the height attribute in the HTML fix this problem?

Comment: IE6 doesn't like width or height auto. As dcaunt mentions below, set the sizes if you know them.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of these images, it's best to specify it. This allows the browser to render the page without reflowing the elements as images are downloaded.